# Overriding the Primefaces error message icon

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have a requirement where I have to display only an error icon when there is a validation error. I am using the iconOnly attribute of primefaces message component for the same. I am trying to override the icon using the below css:

```
      .ui-message-error-icon-new {
      background: url(../img/icon-error.png) no-repeat !important;
 width: 23px; 
 height: 32px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
      }
```

The image is getting displayed but I am unable to get the rid of the primefaces error message border.
Please find the below screenshot:

[image: Override the primefaces error icon]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change that red square color/hide it you can use this:

```
.ui-message-error {
    border:none; 
    background: none;
}
```